# How to return multiple generated columns after insert in MyBatis(Oracle)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, mybatis

I have table with primary key, which consist of several columns. There is batch insert with special Oracle hook - **ignore_row_on_dupkey_index**. That hook allow to ignore Unique Constraint Exception, duplicate records just get ignored, whereas non duplicate get successfully inserted. Using simple jdbc I could easily return primary key(consist of several columns) by code:

```
try(PreparedStatement st = connectio.preparedStatement("insert /* ignore_row_on_dupkey(Table_name, Constraint) */ into TABLE(c1, c2, c3) values(?,?,?)", new String [] {"c1", "c2"})) {
//Batch insert then get generated keys
}
```

Then I could analyze duplicates by iterating over returned keys.

I want to achieve this the same by MyBatis. I found **Options** annotation, which allows to do it by setting property **useGeneratedKeys** and **keyColumn**. The problem is I have complex primary key, whereas **keyColumn** has type String.
Also I dont want to use **SelectKey** annotation.

So my question is can I return several columns value and how by MyBatis or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`keyColumn` allows to specify multiple columns. Here's relevant piece of [the documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#insert_update_and_delete) (note the last sentence):

> keyColumn | (insert and update only) Sets the name of the column in the table with a generated key. This is only required in certain databases (like PostgreSQL) when the key column is not the first column in the table. Can be a comma separated list of columns names if multiple generated columns are expected.

And an example from mybatis [tests](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/ibatis/submitted/selectkey/AnnotatedMapper.xml#L35):

```
<insert id="insertTable2WithGeneratedKeyXml" useGeneratedKeys="true"
    keyProperty="nameId,generatedName" keyColumn="ID,NAME_FRED">
  insert into table2 (name) values(#{name})
</insert>
```